# Task :backend:appengineStart FAILED

Tags: java, android-studio

error when trying to start **appengineStart** from the backend 
this is the error

```
6:37:10 PM: Executing task 'appengineStart'...
Executing tasks: [appengineStart] in project C:\Users\Etch\Desktop\Gradle for android and java\FinalProject\backend
> Task :backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :backend:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:endpointsDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:_zipDiscoveryDocs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :backend:war
> Task :backend:explodeWar
> Task :backend:assemble

> Task :backend:appengineStart FAILED
com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.PathResolver: exception thrown when searching for Google Cloud SDK
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\gcloud
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.PathResolver.getLocationsFromPath(PathResolver.java:97)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.PathResolver.getCloudSdkPath(PathResolver.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk$Builder.discoverSdkPath(CloudSdk.java:719)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk$Builder.build(CloudSdk.java:671)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.standard.DevAppServerStartTask.startAction(DevAppServerStartTask.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineStart'.

  > The Google Cloud SDK could not be found in the customary locations and no path was provided.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
6 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 3 up-to-date
6:37:16 PM: Task execution finished 'appengineStart'.

Answer (score 0):

in build gradle of backend

```
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
    tools.cloudSdkHome="gcloud-sdk-path"
}
```

Where gcloud-sdk-path is found
Documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/gradle-reference#global_properties